# Ruby SSL errors on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, gmail-api

I recently started getting the below error on Heroku with the Gmail API calls

Excon::Errors::SocketError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Heroku support tells me

"We disabled SSLv3 across the entire platform back in October to combat the Poodle vulnerability for inbound calls. For outbound calls you may find you need to switch to TLS if the 3rd party has also disabled SSLv3 - usually updating client gems will help you here."

Google API gem doesn't seem to have been updated recently https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Google APIs Ruby client library doesn't provide an option for setting the SSL version, but you can do it manually on the [Faraday connection](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) using the following code:

```
client.connection.ssl.version = :TLSv1
```

You can inspect `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS` to determine what SSL versions are supported in your environment.